# Get custom colors defined on tailwind config file in js (`colors` object)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I defined some custom colors in the tailwind.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
    darkMode: 'class',
    content: [
        './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,html}',
        './public/index.html'
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                primary: '#E3106E',
                gp: '#19AAF8',
                bl: '#F56622',
                airtel: '#EC1C24',
                robi: '#E30B13',
                teletalk: '#6EB344'
            }
        },
        plugins: []
    },
    gpColor: '#19AAF8'
}
```

In the js file, I can get tailwind colors from the `colors` variable imported from tailwind CSS. Is there any way to get the custom-defined colors in the js file?

Comment: can you provide your code where are you using your custom colors....for now it is inside theme.extend.colors for accessing it. and can be used as var(name of the color)

Comment: I want to use it in js like `colors.primary` as we use the default colors of tailwind css `colors.blue[500]`

Answer (score 1):

You can apply it as

```
import colors from 'tailwindcss/path'
const green = colors.primary;
```

this might help you.

For reference:-
And second thing is that if you are using tailwind CSS then you can use their own CSS colors directly on your code.

Comment: `Cannot find module 'tailwindcss/path' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: You are right. I can use tailwind's default colors. But I want the custom colors defined in tailwind.config.js file. Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible, just try to add normal css as we use to add it while making root css like  :root{
--primary:#000;
} and using it as selector{
var(--primary)
} try to do like this .

Comment: This might be a solution.